# Copy a specific range from a source worksheet to a target worksheet with different path

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim path_feb As String
Dim path_mar As String
Dim wkbk_feb As Workbook
Dim wkbk_mar As Workbook




path_feb = "D:\Tranzit\2016\feb\data_feb.xlsx"
Set wkbk_feb = Workbooks.Open(path_feb)


path_mar = "D:\Tranzit\2016\mar\data_mar.xlsx"
Set wkbk_mar = Workbooks.Open(path_mar)




Worksheets("monthly").Range("A2:A1000").Value = Windows("wkbk_feb").Worksheet("impuls").Range("A2:A1000").Value
Worksheets("monthly").Range("B2:B1000").Value = Windows("wkbk_mar").Worksheet("impuls").Range("A2:A1000").Value

End Sub
```

I need a little help to work this code.

The issue begin here:
`Worksheets("monthly").Range("A2:A1000").Value = Windows("wkbk_feb").Worksheet("impuls").Range("A2:A1000").Value`

So, I have 3 files with different path:

1. `D:\Tranzit\2016\feb\data_feb.xlsx`
2. `D:\Tranzit\2016\\mar\data_mar.xlsx`
3. `D:\Tranzit\2016\data_final.xlsm`

I want to copy from file 1 the range `A2:A1000` from "Sheet" `Impuls` to file 3 in range `A2:A1000` from "Sheet" `monthly`.

and

copy from file 2 the range `A2:A1000` from "Sheet" `Impuls` to file 3 in range `B2:B1000` from "Sheet" `monthly`.

Comment: Please always specify what the "issue" is exactly.

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: It's great that you solved it but it's not a good idea to fix the code in your question. Now the question and answer don't make sense anymore ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `wkbk_feb` and `wkbk_mar` as workbook objects so you need to reference them directly:

```
wkbk_feb.Worksheets("impuls")....
```

instead of activating or selecting anything you should always specify the workbook or worksheet. So it should look something like

```
wkbk_total.Worksheets("monthly")... = wkbk_feb.Worksheets("impuls")....
```

Comment: still doesn't work `wkbk_feb.Worksheet("monthly").Range("A2:A1000").Value = wkbk_feb.Worksheet("impuls").Range("A2:A1000").Value` the error say:  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Comment: THen you're probably trying to access a worksheet that isn't there

Comment: it's there because it opens

Comment: If the workbook opens that doesn't mean that the worksheet is there.